# Entity Framework 6.0.2 extreme slow

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I tried Entity Framework 6.0.2 Code First from NuGet. There is one row in db, condition is just simple as this (EF generated sql):

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Practised] AS [Practised], 
[Extent1].[SourceLangId] AS [SourceLangId], 
[Extent1].[TargetLangId] AS [TargetLangId], 
[Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId]
FROM [dbo].[Dictionary] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NOT NULL)
```

I call the EF like this:

```
IEnumerable<Dictionary> dics = context.Dictionaries.Where(s => s.UserId == userId);
```

The query execution time is about 15 - 16 sec.! When I call exactly same sql directly with ADO, the query execution  time is 0,0010017 sec.
I'm not sure if the time is caused by sql execution, or getting data from SQL to Entity.

Thank you

EDIT:

Dictionary is the Code First entity:

```
public class Dictionary
{
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Practised { get; set; }

    public long SourceLangId { get; set; }
    public virtual Lang SourceLang { get; set; }

    public long TargetLangId { get; set; }
    public virtual Lang TargetLang { get; set; }

    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is `Dictionary` the BCL `Dictionary` or your own custom data type?

Comment: Dictionary is my Code First entity class. Watch the edit. Thnkx

Comment: When you say that EF 6.0.2 is slow, do you mean it is now slow and used to be fast in older versions, or do you mean 6.0.2 is the first version you tried, and that version is slow?

Comment: Also, does the query stay slow if you call it repeatedly? There are a lot of things EF does the first time you use a context, and while 15 seconds is far longer than that should take, it would still be useful to check how long a second query takes.

Comment: I was using the version 5.0.1 with no problem, but on some other projects. Now I'm starting the new project, so I used the last version available.

Comment: The second is still slow, the third is better, like 0,0048153sec.
But when I make a pause between reloads for 10 sec. it is slow again. Pretty weird.

Comment: Also, are you using localDb? You could try running the SQL Profiler to monitor exactly what EF is doing. I suspect that you are dropping & re-creating the database or something like that.

Comment: I set Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DbContext>()); to be sure the database is not recreated, the SQL Profiler log seems to be cleaner a little bit now, but still it is loading a long time on the webhosting.

Comment: How many rows are in your table?  Also, the line of code you mention would not actually execute the query (remember, LINQ is lazy); what line of code *actually* takes 15 seconds?

Comment: post a link as comment in the Blog post about EF 6.0.2: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/12/13/ef6-0-2-rtm-available.aspx Maybe the EF developers have an idea.

Comment: Try to disable PlanCaching: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2012/06/12/entity-framework-5-controlling-automatic-query-compilation.aspx

Comment: To Kirk Woll: There is only one row in database table. When call the linq query and execute it, 15 seconds takes the query execution, the rest of the code is fast enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance was slow due to a bug in EF 6.0.2

See [EF Twitter Account](https://twitter.com/efmagicunicorns/statuses/417801716482854913)